# gradle pass environment variable by file by console/terminal on macOS

Tags: macos, gradle, terminal, environment-variables

I was running my Acceptance test using `IntelliJ`

[image]

Unfortunately sometimes I get this Exception in `IntelliJ` executing specific task as this:

[image]

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'SOME_VARIABLE' in value "classpath:/${SOME_VARIABLE}/acceptance-test.properties"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractEnvironment.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:461)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175)
    ... 67 more
```

But, I would like to execute it using my **terminal** in **macOS**.

I know that, I can't to do it passing all variables as this manner!

`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=xyz SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://config-server EUREKA_SERVICE_URL=http=//eureka-server VAULT_PORT=8200 VAULT_AUTHENTICATION=TOKEN VAULT_TRUST_STORE_PWD=xxxxx  VAULT_TRUST_STORE=file:/Users/joseluisbz/blabla.ts` **`gradle app:acceptanceTest --stacktrace`**

**Is it possible passing the same .env file in terminal?**

Answer (score 0):

Passing ENV values to gradle test is 2 layered

1. using ./gradle.properties or ~/.gradle/gradle.properties to setup the basic ENV variables.  see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties
2. in the `test { }` block setup map of env values using either `systemProperties` or `environment` as per your need. see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test